# Вывод на экран прямоугольного треугольника при помощи цикла while

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;

void main()
{
setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");    

int size, cont = 0, temp = 0;

cout << "Введите размер прямоугольного треугольника: "; cin >> size;


while (temp++ < size)                               
{

    while (cont < size)                         
    {
          if (cont < size) cout << '*'; else cout << ' ';

          cont++;   
    }

    cout << endl;
}


cout << endl;
}
```

[image: Вывод]

1. Помогите пожалуйста с корректным выводом прямоугольного треугольника состоящего из символа **'*'**, исключительно посредством **while**.
2. Почему в моей программе вложенный цикл **while** выполняется только при первой итерации основного цикла **while**, а в последующих игнорируется?

Comment: Ваш вложенный цикл `while` выполняется и при последующих итерациях внешнего `while`, смотрите внимательно что он выводит в соответствии с вашим же условием: `if (cont < size) cout << '*'; else cout << ' ';` (чтобы увидеть замените пробел на другой символ, например `#`).

Comment: Понял, спасибо за помощь ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вероятно вы хотели добиться такого:

```
Введите размер прямоугольного треугольника: 5
*
**
***
****
*****
```

Тогда вы забыли по окончании каждой итерации внешнего цикла сбросить значение переменной `cont`. Подправил ваши циклы:

```
  while (temp++ < size)                         
  {
    while (cont++ < temp)
    {
      cout << '*';
    }
    cont = 0;
    cout << endl;
  }
```